# .NET OData error with decimals: Type mismatch

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, excel, odata

I'm currently trying to get rid of OData error which looks like a problem with decimal parsing/deserializing.

I have working OData API (using System.Web.Http.OData library) in my ASP.NET MVC application and user can download OData Feed file *.odc pointing to said OData API. When there is a decimal in OData API response, such as

```
<d:Value m:type="Edm.Decimal">50.50</d:Value>
```

and user wants to open OData Feed file in Excel (tested on Excel 2016) to fetch data he gets an error:

```
We couldn't get data from the Data Model. Here's the error message we got:
The following system error occurred: Type mismatch.
```

What is intersting is that there is no error when the decimal value has no decimal part, like this:

```
<d:Value m:type="Edm.Decimal">50.00</d:Value>
```

Here's complete API response (with urls cut out):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="xxxxxxxxx" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
  <id>http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/</id>
  <title />
  <updated>2016-06-22T11:01:10Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" href="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
  <entry>
    <id>xxxxx</id>
    <category term="Itm.Erp.Domain.Finance.CashRegistryListView" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <link rel="edit" href="xxxx" />
    <link rel="self" href="xxxx" />
    <title />
    <updated>2016-06-22T11:01:10Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Number>001</d:Number>
        <d:Location m:null="true" />
        <d:Direction>In</d:Direction>
        <d:Person>Sam</d:Person>
        <d:Company>Company</d:Company>
        <d:Date m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-06-06T00:00:00</d:Date>
        <d:IsProcessed m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:IsProcessed>
        <d:ExpenseType m:null="true" />
        <d:Value m:type="Edm.Decimal">50.50</d:Value>
        <d:EffectiveValue m:type="Edm.Decimal">50.50</d:EffectiveValue>
        <d:Seller m:null="true" />
        <d:DocumentNumber m:null="true" />
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

What is the problem with decimals in API response and is there a way to fix it? Does anyone had a similar problem and managed to solve it?